# Is there an analog for std::lock/std::try_lock for try_lock_for and try_lock_until?

Tags: boost, c++14

When acquiring multiple mutexes (or with boost, an iterator range of mutexes), we can use [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) or [`boost::lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions) to avoid deadlocks due to lock ordering.  There are analogous `std::try_lock` and `boost::try_lock` functions using the Lockable concept.

There is also the [TimedMutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TimedMutex) concept, which adds methods `try_lock_for` and `try_lock_until` adds timeout semantics to `try_lock`.  Are there plans for analogs to [`std::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) that provide deadlock avoidance and support the timeout semantics (presumably `std::try_lock_for(Lockable1& lock1, Lockable2& lock2, LockableN& lockn...)` and `std::try_lock_until(Lockable1& lock1, Lockable2& lock2, LockableN& lockn...)`)?

Similarly, are there deadlock-avoiding functions planned for the [SharedTimedMutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SharedTimedMutex) functions `lock_shared`, `try_lock_shared`, `try_lock_shared_for`, and `try_lock_shared_until`?

Answer (score 0):

No, I am not aware of any proposals to add those functions.

I don't believe there has been any past proposal either, but I might have missed one years ago during the C++0x process.

I think the use cases for those functions would be much less common than the uses for `std::lock` and `std::try_lock`